# Spring Social Grails plugin

Tags: grails, spring-social

I am running grails plugin for Spring Social from
https://github.com/synergyj/grails-spring-social-core

When I tried to run the app it throws following error

```
Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.grails.plugins:spock:0.6-SNAPSHOT
```

I had included the `mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots"` and `test(":spock:0.6-SNAPSHOT") { export = false }`

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the latest checkout from the  https://github.com/synergyj/grails-spring-social-core.
The author has changed the setting